# How to use Server-Side-Rendering (SSR) in NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I tried to change a NuxtJS app skeleton so that it uses Server Side Rendering (SSR).
It does not work and I could not find any further documentation besides the SSR-setting in the nuxtJS-config-file.

I setup a NuxtJS application from scratch with `npx nuxi init xxx`.

I added the following setting in **nuxt.config.ts**:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
})
```

Then I started the application from scratch. It still renders everything client side, at least the "Welcome..." text can't be found in the HTML.

How to achieve that?

**Update:**

there is a fundamental difference between setting up a NuxtJS application.

I found out that using `yarn create nuxt-app MyApp` gives a better and more sophisticated result than `npx nuxi init ...`
With the first one, everything is preconfigured as SSR and works out of the box that way. It also provides useful plugins and configs.

Comment: Based on the documentation nuxt3 is already running in SSR by default 
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction#server-side-rendering

Maybe this link can help you as well. 
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By Default the app is configured as a SSR, If you remove it, it will definitely going to work.
2. Also, Add set the app by writing this code inside your nuxt.config.js file, using `target: "server"`:

```
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: true,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: "server",
```